# why loop outputs everytime "kur"

Tags: python

```
i = int(input())
for i in range(5):
   if i <= 5:
      print("kur")
   else:
     print("zadnik")
```

Why everytime this outputs "kur"

Comment: Why shouldn't it? `range(5)` stops at 4.

Comment: You're not testing the user's input, you're testing the iteration variable of the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't think you want/need `for i in range(5):` at all.

Comment: and how does it work and not become an error, when i = input but after this it takes the range number?

Comment: hint : `range(i)` can be used

Answer (score 2):

You've overridden the value of i from your for condition, so your loop is seeing i as the count for the range.
What you want is:

```
    i = int(input())
    for x in range(i+1):
        if...
```

This looks at the count using the input value as your limit